# COMO TRAER UN RANGO ESPECIFICO DE DATOS EN SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin, sqlite

Me gustaria saber si hay alguna manera en SQL de traer un rango especifico de datos de la tabla de una base de datos, tengo 100 registros en phpmyadmin pero solo quiero traer del registro 40 al registro 60, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Y debe ser un grupo específico? ¿O es para paginar? ¿O un simple `SELECT TOP 20 ...` te sirve?

Comment: Es que has puesto diferentes motores, te faltó Oracle, Access, DBase, etc. 

Comment: ¿Qué 20 datos? ¿Aleatoriamente? ¿Los últimos 20 que se registraron? ¿Los 20 primeros ordenados alfabeticamente? ¿Cuál es la estructura de la tabla de la que quieres extraer esos 20 registros? ¿Alguno de sus campos es el que ayudar a definir el criterio de selección para esos 20?

Comment: 2 enlaces que deberán ser como tus nuevas biblias: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/index.htm y http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/mysqlya/

Comment: por favor edita y solo deja la etiqueta del gestor que estés usando

Comment: reformula tu pregunta, en que base de datos y un query que hayas intentado,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que utilizar `limit` y `offset`, `limit` es la cantidad de registros que quieres obtener y `offset` lo que quieres que se salte. A su vez ordenalos por el criterio que necesites.

Comment: gracias me sirvio era exactamente lo que estaba buscando